# mysql version of db2 Query

Tags: mysql, db2

I am new to mysql
I want a Mysql Version of the below Db2 Query

```
        select * from (SELECT AUD.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY aud_id ASC) 
        as rn from AUD) 
        WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 50 ORDER BY REPORTED_TIME ASC
```

Comment: Which RDBM are you using? db2? mysql?

Comment: That query isn't getting you the results you expect in DB2.   The inner query should probably also be ordering by `REPORTED_TIME`.  Ordering by an id is rarely useful, especially if the proper column could be updated.  MySQL doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER()`, you need `OFFSET`/`LIMIT`.